# OOP responsibility assignment

Tags: oop

Lets say we have two classes User & Orders. 
Where should the functionality of getUserOrders (userid) be implemented ?
In the User class or Orders class ?
Should this be in User class as  orders being retrieved related to user or should be Order class as we are retrieving orders

Comment: My opinion is to place it in `User` and the name should be `getOrders`

Comment: I agree with @AbdoAdel. Also, the `Orders` class seems a collection class. It might contain a method `getUserOrders` (2nd best option). A class `Order`, representing a single order should not have a method to get a list of orders for a user.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your OOP design. The key feature to consider is *loose coupling*.

It's a bit difficult to make a determinant decision based on the information you have provided. However, let's take a deeper look at two opposite scenarios.

**Scenario No.1**: You have a `User` class and an `Order` class. You are using composition to link between the two. That's means User class has a list (array, list, linked list, dictionary, associative array, or whatever) consists of Order objects at its disposal. In this case, you would prefer to make a function inside the User class called: `getOrders`. This will retrieve all of the orders associated with the current user.

Order does not know anything about the User entity, and thus it will be *easier to refactor* things in the future when User gets change. User knows about Order but not vice versa. That way we kept on loosely coupled objects (at some degree).

**Scenario No.2**: You have a `User` class and an `Orders` class. Orders class consists of a multi-dimensional array in which there is a User to Order matching. In this case User class does not know anything about order. Here it is better to have `getOrdersByUser` in the Orders class. If we were to refactor our order logic, there was no need of touching the User class, as it is *decoupled* from our Orders.

---

Furthermore, it is better to make your methods to be dependant on instantiation instead of being global hospitable (static). We are talking about *Object* Oriented Programming after all.